# Where to find missing USB Driver for Windows 7 on MacBook Air 2012?

Tags: windows, usb

I successfully installed the latest Boot Camp for Windows 7 on the latest MacBook Air 2012.

My only problem is with one driver for USB controller, which it couldn't be found. Any attempt from device manager to find this missing driver searching automatically or inside the Boot Camp folder was not successful.

Where can I find the missing driver?

Answer (score 1):

The Apple-supplied driver have been overwritten probably by a Windows update. After I reinstalled the Apple Bootcamp Drivers, the problem was solved for me.